# Slow reads in Cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

I recently started a Cassandra cluster with 3 machines. I got it all working fine but after I had to reset one of the nodes (explained in the bottom of this post), I have been having problems with reading from one of the largest tables (see traces below).

I think I have a pretty obvious setup with partitioning and clustering keys and I didn't have this issue before the crash so I don't think thats the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE datachannel_6min (
  channel_id int,
  time_start timestamp,
  power_avg float,
  power_min float,
  power_max float,
  energy float,
  temperature_in float,
  PRIMARY KEY (channel_id, time_start)
);
```

The query is a single row select using the composite key.

```
select * from datachannel_6min where channel_id = 1028 order by time_start desc limit 1;
```

Here is 4 examples of traces... as you can see it's not quite the same all the time.

```
                                                                        activity                  | timestamp    | source   | source_elapsed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------------
                                                                               execute_cql3_query | 09:00:11,930 | 10.1.1.5 |              0
 Parsing select * from datachannel_6min where channel_id = 1042 order by time_start desc limit 1; | 09:00:11,930 | 10.1.1.5 |            102
                                                                              Preparing statement | 09:00:11,930 | 10.1.1.5 |            233
                                             Executing single-partition query on datachannel_6min | 09:00:11,931 | 10.1.1.5 |           1135
                                                                     Acquiring sstable references | 09:00:11,931 | 10.1.1.5 |           1163
                                                                      Merging memtable tombstones | 09:00:11,931 | 10.1.1.5 |           1185
                                                                  Key cache hit for sstable 14912 | 09:00:11,931 | 10.1.1.5 |           1223
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:11,931 | 10.1.1.5 |           1230
                                                                  Key cache hit for sstable 14823 | 09:00:11,984 | 10.1.1.5 |          53805
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:11,984 | 10.1.1.5 |          53851
                                                                  Key cache hit for sstable 14786 | 09:00:12,059 | 10.1.1.5 |         129027
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:12,059 | 10.1.1.5 |         129060
                                                                  Key cache hit for sstable 14749 | 09:00:12,241 | 10.1.1.5 |         311521
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:12,241 | 10.1.1.5 |         311558
                                                                  Key cache hit for sstable 14714 | 09:00:12,242 | 10.1.1.5 |         311843
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:12,242 | 10.1.1.5 |         311849
                                           Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 14913 | 09:00:12,242 | 10.1.1.5 |         312153
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:12,242 | 10.1.1.5 |         312159
                                           Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 14914 | 09:00:12,354 | 10.1.1.5 |         423820
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:12,354 | 10.1.1.5 |         423849
                                           Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 14916 | 09:00:12,354 | 10.1.1.5 |         424455
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:12,354 | 10.1.1.5 |         424463
                                           Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 14915 | 09:00:12,420 | 10.1.1.5 |         490468
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:12,420 | 10.1.1.5 |         490501
                                           Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 14917 | 09:00:12,492 | 10.1.1.5 |         561711
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:12,492 | 10.1.1.5 |         561748
                                         Partition index with 146 entries found for sstable 14918 | 09:00:12,696 | 10.1.1.5 |         766248
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:00:12,696 | 10.1.1.5 |         766306
                       Skipped 0/11 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 09:00:12,696 | 10.1.1.5 |         766323
                                                      Merging data from memtables and 11 sstables | 09:00:12,696 | 10.1.1.5 |         766329
                                                               Read 2 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 09:00:12,773 | 10.1.1.5 |         842632
                                                                                 Request complete | 09:00:12,773 | 10.1.1.5 |         843350



                                                                        activity                  | timestamp    | source   | source_elapsed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------------
                                                                               execute_cql3_query | 09:05:46,255 | 10.1.1.4 |              0
                                                                  Message received from /10.1.1.4 | 09:05:46,250 | 10.1.1.5 |             21
                                             Executing single-partition query on datachannel_6min | 09:05:46,250 | 10.1.1.5 |            520
                                                                     Acquiring sstable references | 09:05:46,250 | 10.1.1.5 |            593
                                                                      Merging memtable tombstones | 09:05:46,250 | 10.1.1.5 |            609
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14912 | 09:05:46,250 | 10.1.1.5 |            630
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14823 | 09:05:46,250 | 10.1.1.5 |            641
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14786 | 09:05:46,250 | 10.1.1.5 |            647
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14749 | 09:05:46,250 | 10.1.1.5 |            654
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14714 | 09:05:46,251 | 10.1.1.5 |            757
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14913 | 09:05:46,251 | 10.1.1.5 |            763
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14914 | 09:05:46,251 | 10.1.1.5 |            770
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14916 | 09:05:46,251 | 10.1.1.5 |            776
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14915 | 09:05:46,251 | 10.1.1.5 |            783
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 14917 | 09:05:46,251 | 10.1.1.5 |            789
 Parsing select * from datachannel_6min where channel_id = 1036 order by time_start desc limit 1; | 09:05:46,255 | 10.1.1.4 |            103
                                                                              Preparing statement | 09:05:46,255 | 10.1.1.4 |            223
                                                                     Sending message to /10.1.1.5 | 09:05:46,256 | 10.1.1.4 |            673
                                          Partition index with 17 entries found for sstable 14918 | 09:05:46,534 | 10.1.1.5 |         283815
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 09:05:46,534 | 10.1.1.5 |         283851
                       Skipped 0/11 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 09:05:46,534 | 10.1.1.5 |         283867
                                                       Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables | 09:05:46,534 | 10.1.1.5 |         283873
                                                               Read 2 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 09:05:46,571 | 10.1.1.5 |         321319
                                                                  Enqueuing response to /10.1.1.4 | 09:05:46,571 | 10.1.1.5 |         321439
                                                                     Sending message to /10.1.1.4 | 09:05:46,571 | 10.1.1.5 |         321613
                                                                  Message received from /10.1.1.5 | 09:05:46,579 | 10.1.1.4 |         323621
                                                               Processing response from /10.1.1.5 | 09:05:46,579 | 10.1.1.4 |         323730                                                               
                                                                                 Request complete | 09:05:46,579 | 10.1.1.4 |         324458



                                                                        activity                  | timestamp    | source   | source_elapsed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------------
                                                                               execute_cql3_query | 05:39:12,430 | 10.1.1.4 |              0
 Parsing select * from datachannel_6min where channel_id = 1030 order by time_start desc limit 1; | 05:39:12,430 | 10.1.1.4 |            164
                                                                              Preparing statement | 05:39:12,430 | 10.1.1.4 |            310
                                                                     Sending message to /10.1.1.6 | 05:39:12,431 | 10.1.1.4 |            829
                                                                  Message received from /10.1.1.4 | 05:39:12,432 | 10.1.1.6 |             19
                                             Executing single-partition query on datachannel_6min | 05:39:12,433 | 10.1.1.6 |            719
                                                                     Acquiring sstable references | 05:39:12,433 | 10.1.1.6 |            742
                                                                      Merging memtable tombstones | 05:39:12,433 | 10.1.1.6 |            769
                                                        Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 1476 | 05:39:12,433 | 10.1.1.6 |            830
                                            Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 1475 | 05:39:12,433 | 10.1.1.6 |            904
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 05:39:12,433 | 10.1.1.6 |            919
                                            Partition index with 2 entries found for sstable 1346 | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           1403
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           1425
                                            Partition index with 2 entries found for sstable 1472 | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           1511
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           1522
                                             Partition index with 0 entries found for sstable 586 | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           1567
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           1578
                                             Partition index with 146 entries found for sstable 5 | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           2132
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           2152
                        Skipped 0/6 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           2177
                                                       Merging data from memtables and 5 sstables | 05:39:12,434 | 10.1.1.6 |           2192
                                                               Read 2 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 05:39:13,106 | 10.1.1.6 |         673858
                                                                  Enqueuing response to /10.1.1.4 | 05:39:13,106 | 10.1.1.6 |         674163
                                                                     Sending message to /10.1.1.4 | 05:39:13,107 | 10.1.1.6 |         674329
                                                                  Message received from /10.1.1.6 | 05:39:13,107 | 10.1.1.4 |         676882
                                                               Processing response from /10.1.1.6 | 05:39:13,107 | 10.1.1.4 |         677118
                                                                                 Request complete | 05:39:13,107 | 10.1.1.4 |         677344



                                                                        activity                  | timestamp    | source   | source_elapsed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------+----------------
                                                                               execute_cql3_query | 05:40:41,322 | 10.1.1.4 |              0
 Parsing select * from datachannel_6min where channel_id = 1028 order by time_start desc limit 1; | 05:40:41,322 | 10.1.1.4 |            104
                                                                              Preparing statement | 05:40:41,322 | 10.1.1.4 |            257
                                                                     Sending message to /10.1.1.5 | 05:40:41,322 | 10.1.1.4 |            569
                                                                  Message received from /10.1.1.4 | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |              9
                                             Executing single-partition query on datachannel_6min | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |            401
                                                                     Acquiring sstable references | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |            410
                                                                      Merging memtable tombstones | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |            427
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 15658 | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |            451
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 15666 | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |            476
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 15892 | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |            489
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 15749 | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |            503
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 15874 | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |            514
                                                       Bloom filter allows skipping sstable 15682 | 05:40:41,324 | 10.1.1.5 |            523
                                          Partition index with 14 entries found for sstable 14918 | 05:40:42,152 | 10.1.1.5 |         828365
                                                Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 05:40:42,152 | 10.1.1.5 |         828406
                        Skipped 0/7 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 05:40:42,152 | 10.1.1.5 |         828422
                                                       Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables | 05:40:42,152 | 10.1.1.5 |         828427
                                                               Read 2 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 05:40:42,300 | 10.1.1.5 |         976825
                                                                  Enqueuing response to /10.1.1.4 | 05:40:42,301 | 10.1.1.5 |         976984
                                                                  Message received from /10.1.1.5 | 05:40:42,301 | 10.1.1.4 |         978829
                                                                     Sending message to /10.1.1.4 | 05:40:42,301 | 10.1.1.5 |         977105
                                                               Processing response from /10.1.1.5 | 05:40:42,301 | 10.1.1.4 |         979018
                                                                                 Request complete | 05:40:42,301 | 10.1.1.4 |         979239
```

This is the history of my cluster and the error that I had.

- Installed 3 nodes in a virtual network in Azure datacenter in West Europe. I started service to log an API into Cassandra. (about 10/s). I started 2nd service that used added data to calculate new data (this is where the select above is used)
- Moved old data (**500 Million rows** in MSSQL) into Cassandra. Ran this parallel to my services in about 3 days.
- [Error] Hard drive was full. I made a stupid mistake and forgotten to add a separate disk for the data. I installed 4 disk on each machine and "merged" them to one (http://blog.metricshub.com/2012/12/27/running-cassandra-on-azure-step-by-step-gotcha-by-gotcha/). I moved the log and data directory to the new disk on all three nodes. Two of the nodes worked fine but the third I had to clean up completely (delete data/logs). I had a replication factor of 2 so no data was lost. I ran **nodetool repair** on the "new" node.
- When I started querying the cluster again I noticed inconsistency in my selects. If I ran a query in Datastax Devcenter I could get no results for a query but after 3-5 tries I got a full reply. I changed my queries to use Quorom instead of ONE which seemed to solve to problem.
- I also ran **nodetool cleanup** on the two good nodes.
- Finally I run nodetool repair on one of the good nodes and are running that on the last node as well right now (takes about 1 day to run).

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

- If you are always going to be querying the most-recent row (`order by time_start desc limit 1;`) then you should consider specifying a `DESC`ending sort direction in your CLUSTERING ORDER.  That will be faster than clustering with `ASC`ending but querying with `DESC`ending.
- Probably the biggest issue I see here, is that your partition (`channel_id = 1028`) is spread out over several SSTABLE files.  Since your data appears to be a time series, you could try using the [DateTieredCompactionStrategy](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datetieredcompactionstrategy).  DateTieredCompactionStrategy groups your data on disk by timestamp.  In theory, that should keep your queries limited to a small number of (or maybe even a single) SSTABLE files.  Especially if you just need the most-recent row.

I would `DROP` (you cannot `ALTER` CLUSTERING ORDER), reload, and recreate your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE datachannel_6min (
  channel_id int,
  time_start timestamp,
  power_avg float,
  power_min float,
  power_max float,
  energy float,
  temperature_in float,
  PRIMARY KEY (channel_id, time_start)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time_start DESC)
AND COMPACTION = {'class': 'DateTieredCompactionStrategy'};
```

There are some options you can set with the DateTieredCompactionStrategy that are outlined in the article I have linked above.  Give it a read through, and make sure that the defaults are right for you, or adjust as need-be.

Comment: Actually, later, I will order other direction as well.. and I will get data from time spans.. so I guess I don't earn anything from changing the clustering order. 

But your article was really interesting. My script added the data "backwards" in time so that might have made the SSTABLES disorganized... but since the SSTABLES have metedata for min/max I still don't see how that could explain my 400-1200ms read times :S 

.. I will read the article over and over now though. Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing altering the tables compaction class will not reorganize old data so I'm thinking about redoing everything right now (clear all data). And adding in the right order this time.

Comment: @Fischer Actually the next time compaction is triggered, it should use the new strategy for the entire keyspace, and that includes existing data.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I read up about DataTierdCompatcion and it looks like it has problems with data being added out-of-order or Backlogs being added since the time for the datapoint does not match the time the record was added to Cassandra. It does sound great for new data but since I am importing data 3 years back in time...

Comment: @Fischer Actually, you're right.  Your imported data will be timestamped at the date of import, not the `time_start`.  But going forward, your new data will be written and compacted together.

Comment: hmm.. Im thinking about redoing everyhintg anyway. Now with DateTieredCompactionStrategy on the table.. and using "USING TIMESTAMP" on the insert query. And also in the right order this time :)

Is it ok to do 1 channel at a time? or is it best to add order by creation instead?